# What is the difference between (int)(2.5) and int(2.5) in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well the title quite self explanatory.
The code:

```
(int)(2.5)
```

produce 2, and the code:

```
int(2.5)
```

produces the same thing. Why the unnecessary parenthesis in the first expression doesn't raise an error?

Thank you.

Comment: unnecessary stuff can give a warning in an IDE, if the program runs why give an error ?

Comment: Because it's not erroneous, It's just redundant

Comment: Why would it be an error? They're not *necessary*, but it's still syntactically valid.

Comment: Well, you call a function but the first note after the name of the function isn't the input variables...

Comment: You're not calling the `int` function. Python's functions are just another object, you can pass them to other functions, for example: `list(map(int, "1 2 3 4".split()))` (`int` is an argument to map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. 
`(int)`  is simply the reference to a callable inside parenthesis - Python resolves the parenthesis, which yields simply `int` - and then makes the call.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that even in C, if you put a function inside parenthesis, it would do just the same. Types in C are a completely different thing than named variables or functions - and the special cast syntax works only for them.